# Solution rebuild fails 30% of the time

Tags: c#, c++, projects-and-solutions, rebuild, multiple-projects

We have over 100 projects in a Solution and some of the projects include other projects as project references. The Clean-Build/Rebuild took too much time, so I searched and found a pretty good solution for optimizing the build/rebuild time:

1. Setting the same output path for Debug/Release in all projects with the difference of $(Configuration).
2. Setting the Project references's Copy Local to false, because the project, that is referenced, should be there.

After multiple testing, I have found out that the VS Solution's rebuild fails 30% of the time due to `metadata * could not be found`.
I know what the error means, but I do not know how it comes to that.

Has anybody any idea, how to improve the success of Solution's Rebuild?

Comment: woah 100 projects, it must would be lunch time before vs2017 would even open

Comment: VS can fail to rebuild assembly dlls if they are locked. That can cause "metadata could not be found" error. However this error is too generic (VS builds projects multi threaded and there was no referenced project dlls available). I believe  there should be more specific error message in the log. Do you have any other kind of error in the output window?

Comment: It looks like some projects may produce output files with the same name interfering with each other.

Comment: Have you tried disabling multihtreaded compilation?

Comment: @saruman: it has it's pros :)

Comment: @oleksa: There were just same, but multiple errors for different *.dll files.

Comment: @m.rogalski: I have changed the max number of parallel project builds from 4 to 2 and I do not get the error. But it takes more time to rebuild.

Comment: @ursyka That's a common problem when dealing with multi-dependant projects. Most likely when you hit build, project tries to build 4 projects from the last branch of dependency tree but the problem starts comming out when one build of one project is faster than another one ( like 99% of cases ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequent problem with rebuilds failing sometimes is (as has been noted in the comments) parallel builds, when there are dependencies between projects (i.e. one build target requires other projects to be built first, as it consumes the output of the projects.)

It is possible to set build dependencies in VS - VS version isn't stated, but you should be able to right click on a project, and select 'Build Dependencies' - which then gives you two options: Build Dependencies, and Build Order.

Using these options you can define which projects depend on others (i.e. prevent VS from trying to build projects where the ones on which it depends haven't yet been built) and, if you need to, specify a specific order for projects to build in.

Provided you get your dependencies right, it should ensure the correct ordering, without sacrificing the parallel build (which, with so many projects, you're going to want to keep, I suspect.)

See: [How to: Create and Remove Project Dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-and-remove-project-dependencies)

Comment: Is it not so, that VS makes the Build Order by itself?

Comment: VS knows about project build order from projects references, I never had to set build dependencies manually

Comment: Yes, the build order should be automatic, but you can change it if it gets confused. Which it does sometimes.